# C++20 coroutines using final_suspend for continuations

Tags: c++, c++20, continuations, c++-coroutine

**BACKGROUND**

After being convinced that [C++ stackless coroutines are pretty awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163510/are-stackless-c20-coroutines-a-problem). I have been implementing coroutines for my codebase, and realised an oddity in final_suspend.

**CONTEXT**

Let’s say you have the following **final_suspend** function:

```
final_awaitable final_suspend() noexcept
{
    return {};
}
```

And, **final_awaitable** was implemented as follows:

```
struct final_awaitable
{
    bool await_ready() const noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }
    default_handle_t await_suspend( promise_handle_t h ) const noexcept
    { 
        return h.promise().continuation();
    }
    void await_resume() const noexcept {}
};
```

If continuation here was retrieved atomically from task queue **and** the task queue is potentially empty (which could occur any time between **await_ready** and **await_suspend**) then **await_suspend** must be able to return a blank continuation.

It is my understanding that when **await_suspend** returns a handle, the returned handle is immediately resumed (5.1 in [N4775](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4775.pdf) draft). So, if there was no avaliable continuation here, any application crashes as resume is called on an invalid coroutine handle after receiving it from **await_suspend**.

The following is the execution order:

```
final_suspend                        Constructs final_awaitable.
    final_awaitable::await_ready     Returns false, triggering await_suspend.
    final_awaitable::await_suspend   Returns a continuation (or empty continuation).
        continuation::resume         This could be null if a retrieved from an empty work queue.
```

No check appears to be specified for a valid handle (as it is if await_suspend returns bool).

**QUESTION**

1. How are you suppose to add a worker queue to **await_suspend** without a lock in this case? Looking for a scalable solution.
2. Why doesn't the underlying coroutine implementation check for a valid handle.

A contrived example causing the crash is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TF64ZR).

**SOLUTION IDEAS**

1. Using a dummy task that is an infinite loop of **co_yield**. This is sort of wasted cycles and I would prefer not to have to do this, also I would need to create seperate handles to the dummy task for every thread of execution and that just seems silly.
2. Creating a specialisation of [**std::coroutine_handle**](https://godbolt.org/z/aR3bo3) where resume does nothing, returning an instance of that handle. I'd prefer not specialise the standard library. This also doesn't work because **coroutine_handle<>** doesn't have **done()** and **resume()** as virtual.
3. *EDIT 1 16/03/2020* Call continuation() to atomically retrieve a continuation and store the result in the **final_awaitable** structure, **await_ready** world return true if there wasn't a continuation available. If there was a continuation available **await_ready** would return false, **await_suspend** would then be called and the continuation returned (immediately resuming it).
   This doesn't work because the value returned by a task is stored in the coroutine frame and if the value is still needed then the coroutine frame must not be destroyed. In this case it is destroyed after **await_resume** is called on the **final_awaitable**.
   This is only an issue if the task is the last in a chain of continuations.
4. *EDIT 2 - 20/03/2020* Ignore the possibility of returning a usable co routine handle from **await_suspend**. Only resume continuation from top level co routine. This doesn't appear as efficient.

**01/04/2020**

I still haven't found a solution that doesn't have substantial disadvantages. I suppose the reason I'm caught up on this is because await_suspend appears to be designed to solve this exact problem (being able to return a corountine_handle). I just cannot figure out the pattern that was intended.

Comment: Is not it possible to define a `bool await_suspend( promise_handle_t h)` in `final_awaitable` and conditionnaly resume the continuation in the body of this function?

Comment: It is possible to return true or false to conditionally resume the coroutine but not a continuation. Still, Its strange that the coroutine handle isn't checked before resuming.  It seems to check a flag before resuming any other coroutine with await_ready but doesn't here. Maybe it's just my understanding gap... I just don't see how you are suppose to actually suspend when you have no continuation available and the coroutine isn't ready (and returns coroutine_handle<>).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [std::noop_coroutine](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0913r0.html) as a blank continuation.

Comment: Has that made it into C++20?

Comment: Yes, it did! See _17.12.4 No-op coroutines [coroutine.noop]_ in  [N4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf)

Comment: Neato! Thanks, I'll try this I'd put that part of the project on hold so I can just continue where it left off :D I'll mark this as right answer if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

What about: (Just a large comment in fact.)

```
struct final_awaitable
{
    bool await_ready() const noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool await_suspend( promise_handle_t h ) const noexcept
    { 
        auto continuation = h.promise().atomically_pop_a_continuation();
        if (continuation)
           continuation.handle().resume();
        return true;//or whatever is meaningfull for your case.
    }
    void await_resume() const noexcept {}
};
```

Comment: Thats a good solution, however the reason that I prefer the coroutine_handle form is that it doesn't grow the stack with each continuation.

Comment: @DavidLedger And if the continuation ends in calling a continuation that ends in calling another continuation... all that coroutine's states will not be destroyed so that the heap could be filled before the stack. I suppose it would be simpler to make a normal function that calls a coroutine, waits for the promise, destroy the coroutine and then calls the continuation.

Comment: Yeh, there is usually more heap avaliable than stack, so thats the approach I prefer for scalability.